# Capitalization of explanation of abbreviations

Tags: abbreviations, capitalization

I'm writing a rather tehnical report with a lot of abbreviations such as *QoS (quality of service)*, *AES (Advanced Encryption Standard)* and *HMAC (Hash-based Message Authentication Code)*.

When should the explanation of the abbreviation be capitalized? For example, should it be *quality of service* or *Quality of Service*? How does one know what to use for the vast majority of technical abbreviations?

Answer (score 23):

According to the [Wikipedia Manual of Style](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Manual_of_Style_%28capital_letters%29), these are some rules on the matter (I'll paste it):

> When showing the source of an acronym, initialism, or syllabic abbreviation, emphasizing the letters that make up the acronym is undesirable:
>
> **Incorrect**: FOREX (FOReign EXchange)
>   **Incorrect**: FOREX (**for**eign **ex**change)
>   **Correct**: FOREX (foreign exchange)
>
> If it is necessary to do so, for example, to indicate the etymology, use italics: FOREX (from "*for*eign *ex*change")
>
> Specifically, do not apply initial capitals in a full term that is a common noun just because capitals are used in the abbreviation.
>
> **Incorrect** (not a name/proper noun):       We used Digital Scanning (DS) technology
>   **Correct**:     We used digital scanning (DS) technology
>   **Correct** (name/proper noun): produced by the British Broadcasting Corporation (BBC)

So: don't capitalize if the words are "common" and capitalize if the acronym refers to proper names. See also page 81 in [this document](https://docs.google.com/viewer?a=v&q=cache:AdJCa4ZJZw0J:www.sti.nasa.gov/publish/sp7084.pdf%20capitalization%20acronyms&hl=en&gl=it&pid=bl&srcid=ADGEESgBEV7RkVkNRe2Z6OHVCRcou11mEOcwGv8AU0dYIH_DFazbERWEkwr-Fx93dqWnsdSjsvQsefkwtV9P3NRTJquj1GVPQDUJdnDIYv2rTmPY1hhqqeV2LGpfyjD-jwpTYBXhPYjy&sig=AHIEtbRL9KgBNS0vLZ9y5SD8QJZVwjHaAw).

Comment: Strictly speaking, this is Wikipedia 's Manual of Style rule on showing the *source of an abbreviation*. There's no mention on when or how to capitalise abbreviations.

Comment: @Hugo: There is no need for that to be mentioned, since the OP asked how should we capitalise the _source_ of an abbreviation and _not_ the abbreviation itself. He wrote "_What I can't seem to grasp is when should the explanation of the abbreviation be capitalized?_". I think this answer explains that.

Comment: @Alenanno Oops, I misread the question and therefore that Wikipedia text is a good example. Thanks!

Comment: @Hugo: No problem! :)

Comment: Why is *Wikipedia*'s manual of style authoritative? Seems an odd source to quote.

Answer (score -2):

A simple question with a complicated answer. First of all, the abbreviations you mention are actually called [acronyms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Acronym), i.e. words that are composed of parts of several words. An abbreviation, on the other hand, stands only for a single word.

As for the actual answer:

Here are some rules I can think of that govern the capitalization of the letters in an acronym:

- "QoS" is about "Quality" and about "Service", the "of" only serves to connect those two. So to mark the "of" as not so important, it is lower case.
- Letters in an acronym can also be mixed case when one partial word contributes more than 1 letter to the acronym, and is therefore in lowercase so as not to imply that there are more words. Example: BVerfG stands for **B**undes-**Verf**assungs-**G**ericht, the highest German court (can't think of a quick example in English)
- Acronyms can also turn into regular words with regular capitalization, if they are pronouncable as regular words, and if they come into common usage. Example: "Laser" comes from "LASER" (**L**ight **A**mplification through **S**timulated **E**mmission of **R**adiation)

Comment: Where is the actual answer?  The question isn't about capitalisation of acronyms themselves, but whether you should retain the capitals if you write the expanded form.