# captilization of words with abbreviation

Tags: word-usage, capitalization, abbreviations

I always used to capitalize first letter of words that have abbreviation. For example,

> Methicillin Resistant Staphylococcus Aureus (MRSA).

I do this more often when i mention the abbreviation within the brackets. Is it correct? if so, is it essential to capitalize these abbreviated words?

Comment: Related: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/40427/capitalization-of-explanation-of-abbreviations, http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/137965/should-i-capitalize-the-phrase-that-has-its-abbreviation-following

Answer (score 2):

The abbreviation exists to serve as a shorter form of the word or phrase, not the word or phrase existing to serve as an expansion of the abbreviation. (99% of the time, some backronyms to the contrary).

As such, the capitalisation of the abbreviation should not affect the form of the word.

An exception would be if you were to do the opposite, where it is an option:

> There had been an outbreak of MRSA (Methicillin-resistant Staphylococcus aureus).
>
> We found the approach to QoS (quality of service) caused more problems than it sovled.

Or:

> There had been an outbreak of MRSA (Methicillin-Resistant Staphylococcus Aureus).
>
> We found the approach to QoS (Quality of Service) caused more problems than it sovled.

Here you **may** choose, as a matter of style, to make the capitalisation of the expanded form match that of the abbreviation, because you are explicitly including the full form as an explanation of the abbreviation, rather than the shortened form as an abbreviation of the term.

Answer (score 1):

I see that the Centers for Disease Control expands MRSA as "Methicillin-resistant Staphylococcus aureus" at the beginning of a sentence, and (with the abbreviation *S. aureus* for *Staphylococcus aureus*) as "methicillin-resistant S. aureus" - see [here](http://www.cdc.gov/mrsa/) for the first reference, [here](http://www.cdc.gov/mrsa/lab/index.html) for the second, in the paragraph beginning "Approximately 10% ..." So it seems that one ought to follow standard capitalization rules in the spelled-out words.

Comment: Staphylococcus is capitalized according to convention, as the name of a genus of bacteria.

Comment: True; and I subsequently deleted my responding comment, which was simply to clarify that the reason "aureus" is not capitalized is that no word in a species name is capitalized, except the name of the genus.

Comment: I think we're sorted out now. ;)

Comment: That's right about the Staph aureus part. I didn't realize that I wrote a name of a bacteria. I guess I chose a bad example. Never mind, I think I got the answer for my question.